On connected sum of compact manifolds along a submanifold
Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two compact manifolds of dimension $n\ge 3$. Let us have embeddings $i_1: K \to M_1$ and $i_2: K \to M_2$ for a closed manifold $K$ of dimension at most $n-1$ such that the normal bundles $N_1$ and $N_2$ corresponding to $i_1$ and $i_2$, respectively, are isomorphic. Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be tubular neighborhoods of $i_1(K)$ and $i_2(K)$, that are identified with the total spaces of $N_1$ and $N_2$, respectively. It is easy to find a homeomorphism $f: U_1 - i_1(K) \to U_2 - i_2(K)$. Let us obtain $M_1\#_K M_2$ from $(M_1 - i_1(K))\cup(M_2 - i_2(K))$ by gluing $U_1 - i_1(K)$ and $U_2 - i_2(K)$ along $f$. This is the connected sum of $M_1$ and $M_2$ along the submanifold $K$ described here. Let $M = M_1 \cup_K M_2$ be the union of $M_1$ and $M_2$ along $K$.
I have the following related questions about this construction.

Is $M_1 \#_K M_2$ always a closed (compact with boundary) manifold? If not in general, then does it at least hold if both $M_1$ and $M_2$ are closed?
Is the quotient $M/K$ homeomorphic to the wedge $M_1/(U_1 - i_1(K)) \vee M_2/(U_2 - i_2(K))$?
If the answer to the above question is YES, then is the quotient map $g :M \to M/K$ a homotopy equivalence?

All these questions are motivated by the corresponding questions (having positive answers) to the usual connected sum along a point.

I don't understand question 2: there's no K in M.

@MarcoGolla $K$ is embedded in $M_1$ and $M_2$, and $M$ is the union of $M_1$ and $M_2$ along $K$. Isn't there a copy of $K$ in $M$ then?

No, you're exactly gluing $M_1\setminus K_1$ and $M_2\setminus K_2$, so there's no $K$.

@MarcoGolla then what is the meaning of Gael Meigniez's answer below? It looks like he finds my question 2 ok and he thinks the answer is "yes".

You should ask him, not me :)

The natural submanifold of your $M_1 #_K M_2$ is the sphere bundle $S_K = \partial U_i$ over $K$. One has $(M_1 #_K M_2)/S_K \cong (M_1/K) \vee (M_2/K)$. Marco is commenting about this setting. You also look at the (non-manifold) $M$ which is simply $M_1 \cup_K M_2$, for which one also has $(M_1 \cup_K M_2)/K \cong (M_1/K) \vee (M_2/K)$. When the normal bundle to $K$ has a section, then $S_K$ contains (perhaps some number of distinct) submanifolds diffeomorphic to $K$. You could look into collapsing these, but that's probably not what you want.

Note that "closed" means "compact without boundary".
Here are answers.
(1): Yes, if $M_1$ and $M_2$
are closed manifolds then $M_1\sharp_KM_2$ is a closed manifold. If
$M_1$ and $M_2$
are compact manifolds with boundary and if $i_1(K)$ is interior to $M_1$
(i.e. disjoint from the boundary $\partial M_1$)  and if $i_2(K)$ is interior to $M_2$, then $M=M_1\sharp_KM_2$ is a compact manifold with boundary. You can prove that by giving an atlas.
(2) Your questions (2) and (3) make sense if there is an embedding of $K$ into $M$. This will be guaranteed if  the common normal bundle to $i_1$ and $i_2$ admits a nonvanishing section. Then, the answer to (2) is Yes.
(3) Probably almost always no, if $K$ is not reduced to one point. For example, still under the hypothesis that the common normal bundle to $i_1$ and $i_2$ admits a nonvanishing section, then you get an inclusion $K\subset M$ as a submanifold which will in general not be homotopic to a constant map; while the mapping $K\to M/K$ is homotopic to a constant map. You can also think to the case $K=$ two points and $M_1=M_2=S^1$.

Thank you for your answer. This is in response to a comment by Marco Golla on my question that $M/K$ does not make sense since there is no $K$ in $M$. In your answer, you found part (2) of my question ok and you said that $M/K$ is indeed homeomorphic to the space I described. So, does part (2) of my question still make sense to you?
